# Checking launchOptions in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have converted my codes to swift 3 and I have submitted to app store. When they open app, it crash at first time. As a result, I check my crashlog and it crash at this line.

```
    if let myLaunchOptions: NSDictionary = launchOptions as NSDictionary? {
```

My overall code is like this. I know that launchOptions can be nil and it might not even be NSDictionary. That's why I have checked like that and it fail at that line. May I know how else to check/prevent with swift 3?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if let myLaunchOptions: NSDictionary = launchOptions as NSDictionary? {
        let test = myLaunchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as! NSDictionary
        let userActivity = test["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as! NSUserActivity
        NSLog("test1:" + String(describing: userActivity))
        continueUserActivity(userActivity)
        }
```

My crash log is here.

[image]

Comment: What's the point of casting to `NSDictionary`? It's Swift code, leave it as a Swift dictionary.

Comment: And what's the error from the crash?

Comment: If you dont know the data type, please use the below line.

Comment: ah..sorry @rmaddy. my bad. yes. i will use dictionary. I am used to objective-c code. I have updated to show crash log.

Comment: That doesn't show the error. There should be an error in the crash log.

Comment: I am trying to check error but I can't find detail from that. The one I have is crashlog from apple. https://gist.github.com/khantthulinn/1daa6cd0756ace7c0fbbfa6578f3fa6f

But I don't know how to find where it crash from there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be checking and obtaining user activity like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if let userActivityDictionary = launchOptions?[.userActivityDictionary] as? [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any],
        let userActivity = userActivityDictionary[.userActivityType] as? NSUserActivity {
        continueUserActivity(userActivity)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I have used yours and it fix my issue. Apple now approve my app. Thanks you.

Comment: I don't think this is totally right; `.userActivityType` would return an NSString from the dictionary.

Answer (score 9):

I had to update @David Rodrigues' solution in order to make this work in Swift 4 because `.userActivityType` is `NSString`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if let userActivityDict = launchOptions?[.userActivityDictionary] as? [AnyHashable : Any],
        let userActivity = userActivityDict["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity {
        continueUserActivity(userActivity)
    }

    return true
}
```